# Email layout broken in IE, image with colspan

Tags: html, css, html-email

I have a table based HTML email layout that breaks in IE. I set 3 cells widths, then in the next row I use colspan 3 and place an image equal to the width the the 3 cells, this negates the widths set.

Full example to compare:
http://codepen.io/mikevoermans/pen/bLpjB

An excerpt of the email:

```
<table width="500" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1">

<tr>
    <td colspan="3" style="font-size: 1px; line-height: 1px; background: #838383;" height="10">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td width="10%" style="background: #838383;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="84%" style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 10px; line-height: 16px; color: #f2f2f2; text-align: right; background: #838383;">
        Trouble viewing this message? 
    </td>
    <td width="6%" style="background: #838383;">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td colspan="3"><!-- This is where it breaks the layout -->
        <img src="http://placedog.com/500/200" alt="" width="500" height="200" style="display:block; border:none;" />
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

If I wrap the row around the image in a new table (closing the first table and starting a new table after it) the layout is corrected as well. I guess I'm looking to know why its breaking, vs a hacky way to fix it, I already have that.

Comment: I see the image fix using inline styles, but I think the root of the problem is that IE is having an issue with % widths on your `td`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the inline style to set the image width to 100% and the height to 200px.

```
<img src="http://placedog.com/500/200" alt="" style="width:100%;height:200px;display:block; border:none;" />
```

Comment: Seems as though I can keep the width and height attributes and just add the width: 100% to the style tag, thanks, this is what I was looking for.